# Creating a JOB file in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a JOB that should be executed once time per minute, so i created a job.py that uses this library https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/.

```
import time

import schedule


def capturar_placas_cloud_alpr():
    print('hi')


schedule.every(1).minutes.do(capturar_placas_cloud_alpr())

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

But the "hi" message never appear. I'm newbie in python so i don't know if i should initialize this file to start Schedule execution.

Answer (score 0):

The [`do`](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#schedule.Job.do) function of schedule should get a reference to a function (and not the output of the call to the function):

```
schedule.every(1).minutes.do(capturar_placas_cloud_alpr)
                                                      #^ Note that I didn't add this () here
```

In your code, basically what `do` got is None, because the call to `capturar_placas_cloud_alpr` in your code returned `None`.

Comment: I removed the "()" as you mentioned, but the "hi" message don't appear in console.

Comment: Did you wait a complete 1 minute for the `hi` to appear in the console? :)

Comment: Yeah, i'm wating more than 5 minutes and nothing.

Comment: python version? windows/linux?

Comment: Python 3.6.6, Linux distro Fedora 28

Comment: I tried put a breakpoint in "schedule.every..." line but debug never stop there, in other words this line is never called

Comment: try to add `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` above the `schedule...` line and run this.

Comment: I putted the "pdb.set_trace()" above the schedule but nothing happens.

Comment: Something there doesn't work, not related to the `schedule` at all. Try to run a python script only with the `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`

Comment: look, this jobs.py is inside a django project, so i start my project with "runserver" i don't run script directly.

Comment: So this is a complete question now. Please try this not inside the django project and let us know.

Comment: If i run directly "python jobs.py" this works. But i need run it inside a django project, any tips ?